# Copy between Word and Outlook does not work; copying seems to work but it just does not paste anything

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-word, copy-paste

Office 2007 plus is installed on my machine. `Copy link` appears in both Word and Outlook. You can copy some text and then paste it, it just does not paste anything.

The paste works in Notepad or Excel so it is in the buffer. What could be wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried to paste special to say `plain text` to see if that pastes?

Comment: Did not try the paste special. It was simple text though, no CSV or tables involved. I wonder if that option was even available.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed by repairing office 2007.

> Go to Start-> control Panel-> Add Remove Software -> wait the for list to be
>   populated. Select Microsoft Office 2007. Right click and click change.
>   In the dialog box, select repair.